# My Eclipse can compile but I can't find a JDK!

Tags: eclipse, java

I've installed Eclipse on a Windows machine some time ago. A couple of days back I was doing some Java coding and I noticed I don't have a JDK, but still Eclipse could compile & run the Java classes. Does it have a compiler included?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes Eclipse contains it's own incremental compiler.

> An incremental Java compiler.
>   Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it
>   is based on technology evolved from
>   VisualAge for Java compiler. In
>   particular, it allows to run and debug
>   code which still contains unresolved
>   errors.

For some history take a look here:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/06/28/whats-new-in-eclipse-3-2-java-development-tools.html

Comment: can I execute it from a command prompt/shell? I mean, what's the executable's name?

Comment: Yes I beleive you can. Back in the day people used to use the Eclipse compiler over the Java one for compiling JSP pages as it was quicker. Here's a link about running the Eclipse compiler http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And here's some more characters.

Comment: funny. here are some more as well.