# Why doesn't Eclipse need me to configure a JDK?

Tags: eclipse, compilation, java

I recently downloaded Eclipse onto a Windows 7 machine. The machine already had a JRE but I noticed it didn't have a JDK. I was afraid I would have to download the JDK and then hook Eclipse up to it. I was (pleasanly) surprised when I was able to code, compile and run in Eclipse right out of the box. However, now I'm confused. From what I know about Java, Eclipse should need a JDK to compile code and a JRE to execute it.

The best I can think of is...

1. Eclipse is packaged with a JDK (if this is true, I can't find the JDK on my computer)
2. I'm way out in left field and don't understand JDKs as well as I thought I did.

Admittedly more of a curiosity question, why am I able to compile java without a JDK?

Comment: Opps. Found duplicates of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289232/my-eclipse-can-compile-but-i-cant-find-a-jdk?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has an internal compiler for some time now. Several years ago it needed a JDK but for now a JRE will suffice.

However if you want to browse or debug in the Java source code, a JDK is better.

Comment: Partly correct. Eclipse always had an internal compiler and never needed a JDK for basic Java functionality. Some plugins may require JDK, if they rely on other tools included in the JDK, but not the core Eclipse Java Tools.

Comment: I can remember installing an Eclipse years ago which needed a JDK. What was the reason for that then?