# Eclipse programs not running?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to `java`.  I have just got `Eclipse` working (somehow) lol. well my programs are running fine until-

I save a program, close out of eclipse, and re-open the program.  when I try to run it the same way that works for all the other programs, I am getting a message asking to "run with ant build".  for some reason `eclipse` will not run any of my programs that have been closed out and re-opened, but will run new programs just fine.

does anyone know how to fix this???

thanks

EDIT- i would post an image, but I do not have at least 10 reputation..  what is happening is I go to open `file => C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx\workspace\t\src\t (t is the program's name)` and then I open it, and run it.  When I run it (either F11 or the run button) it pops up a window saying "select what to run as", and the only options are 2 ant build icons.  Running as ant build does not work, because this isn't an antbuild file.  I created a new program just to test, (from scratch) and everything compiles and runs fine...

everything is compiling and running fine on NEW programs, but I just tried opening a program I created yesterday, and it is giving me the error mentioned above.. it was running perfectly fine yesterday. also, I have JDK installed at home, and I am getting this same exact problem.. JDK isn't the source.

EDIT- i have 10 rep now.  Here's an image of what was happening before the fix

[image: problem]

Comment: are you sure?  I have read that eclipse comes with its own compiler.  also, my programs are running fine (meaning they are compiling fine) until I close them, re-open, and try to run them again.  also, I have JDK installed at my home computer, and I am getting this same sort of problem.. I don't think it's caused by JDK

Comment: Then problem lies elsewhere, you need to be more clear with that :)

Comment: what else do you need to know? i'd be happy to tell more, but I am just new to java and don't know what really needs to be told

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't run?

Comment: "eclipse will not run any of my programs that have been closed out and re-opened"---> "will not run" doesn't provide enough information about the issue, isn't it? May be providing more context like what is happening in "will not run" case may help, are you seeing any messages on eclipse windows etc.,

Comment: I either hit the F11 or just the "run" button at the top- for new programs, it compiles and runs just fine.  but when I just opened this tutorial type of program I was working on yesterday (by going into the "src" file in the folder that is auto created upon creation of the project [in the workspace folder]), when i try to run it, it says "select what to run" and the only options are ant build files.  when I hit "ok" the build fails because this isn't an ant build file. ???

Comment: i would post an image, but I do not have at least 10 reputation..  what is happening is I go to open file => C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx\workspace\t\src\t (t is the program's name) and then I open it, and run it.  When I run it (either F11 or the run button) it pops up a window saying "select what to run as", and the only options are 2 ant build icons.  Running as ant build does not work, because this isn't an antbuild file.  I created a new program just to test, (from scratch) and everything compiles and runs fine...

Comment: You shouldn't have to open a file. It should be in your package explorer, saved from your past workspace. If it's not, then open your project

Comment: In eclipse package explorer if you right-click on the project you're trying to run and navigate to "Run As" is "Java Application" listed in that menu? If not then you are either not in the Java Perspective (go to Window > Show View > Java to open the Java Perspective), or your project isn't a Java project for some reason.

Comment: @peeskillet, thank you.  so how do I open a project? I know how to open a file (what I was doing was opening the file from the "src" folder created in the workspace folder), for some reason it is not coming up on the package explorer bar.. I did change my workspace location, but the program should still run??

Comment: @samYonnou it is not in the package explorer menu.. this might be because I changed my "workspace" folder location, but shouldn't the program still run?

Comment: your project needs to be tied to your workspace to be able to be run

Comment: you can add your project into the workspace by doing File > Import > Existing Projects Into Workspace

Comment: See my answer below. It's a step by step

Comment: _"but the program should still run??"_ No it shouldn't because you're trying to run the .java file. .java files are not runnable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *" what is happening is I go to open file.."*

You don't want to open the file. You want to open the project

- Click on File menu
- Click on import
- Click on General
- Select on Existing Projects into Workspace. CLlick Next
- Click Browse to search from your project
- Select the Project, Click OK
- Click Finish

The project should now show in your package explorer and you can then run it.

Comment: thank you, i think this worked.. I have yet to run the program, but there are a couple import errors.. (not related to your answer).  I imported a couple things because the tutorial told me to, and I think I will have to re-import them.. but I think your solution works.  I would upvote you, but I don't have 15 rep.

Comment: my code:

package t;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class c {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText("Hello worl5d!");
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
 }

}

Comment: Also, you may want to ask another question as this is a Q & A site, not really a help desk. Also, someone else may benefit from the question you ask. If you ask it in a comment, it will not be searchable to the public.

Comment: I only have 13 rep after the accept.  also about the imports, they were running fine yesterday.  I have eclipse EE , and I suppose EE comes with SWT.. ?

Comment: I'm not sure then. I only use the Android version of Eclipse. I'm more of a NetBeans person. You should ask another question here if you really need those imports

Answer (score 0):

To run program `JRE` is enough.

If you want to build project you need `JDK`.

`Eclipse` is a `Java` application and it works without `JDK`,but it needs `JDK` to build a project.
`Eclipse` is not compiler or something like that, it's only an `IDE`.

Comment: Assuming he has a recent version of Eclipse he doesn't need JDK since it comes with it's own compiler (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863657/why-doesnt-eclipse-need-me-to-configure-a-jdk).

Comment: ^^^ that is exactly what I was thinking.  everything is compiling and running fine on NEW programs, but I just tried opening a program I created yesterday, and it is giving me the error mentioned above.. it was running perfectly fine yesterday.  also, I have JDK installed at home, and I am getting this same exact problem.. JDK isn't the source.